# how to get json response for build details from Jenkins build after it finishes

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, webhooks

I have a Jenkins Server which runs a Jenkins job - JobA

and I have a Java Spring boot web service, where I store the Jenkins build data and serve it to various other systems.

I want that whenever JobA finishes each build, it should call an endpoint on my web service and post the build data (bascically the same data that I get from calling the Jenkins API: `https://<my-jenkins-server>/job/JobA/<buildNumber>/api/json`) to the end point of my web service, which accepts a POST requests and JSON payload to update the build details like job name, build number, build result, build url, build duration, timestamp, test results etc. in my database.

The endpoint of my web service should still be called even if the build fails.

I can already get all this data from the above REST API call, but I do not want to use that because, using that if I want to get the updated data in my database, I will have to poll the Jenkins REST API multiple times, (like maybe every 15 minutes or more frequently) which will increase the load on my Jenkins server.

I know that I can set up a Jenkins job to either call a script or call another downstream job through which I can then call a `curl` `POST` request to my end point.

But my problem is that I do not know where/how to get the JSON data for the build be sent in the `POST` request?

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the lastbuild information and there is a field called `building` which says if the build is running or not.

https://host/job/project/lastBuild/api/json?depth=1

Comment: but, to do this, I will still have to poll the Jenkins REST API multiple times periodically too right?

Comment: yes, you need to pool every x seconds or minutes.
Also you can add a trigger in your job to make a call to an api and this will alert your webservice.